# SpringData MongoDb, how to count distinct of a query?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, distinct

I'm doing paginated search with mongoDb in my Springboot API.

For a customer search path, I'm building a query with a bunch of criteria depending on the user input.
I then do a count to display the total number of results (and the computed number of page associated)

```
  Long total = mongoTemplate.count(query, MyEntity.class);
```

I then do the paginated query to return only current page results

```
query.with(PageRequest.of(pagination.getPage(), pagination.getPageSize()));
query.with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "creationDate"));
List<MyEntity> listResults = mongoTemplate.find(query, MyEntity.class);
```

It all works well.
Now on my total results, i often have multiple result for the same users, I want to display those in the paginated list, but I also want to display a new counter with the total distinct user that are in that search.

I saw the findDistinct parameter

```
mongoTemplate.findDistinct(query, "userId", OnboardingItineraryEntity.class, String.class);
```

But I do not want to retrieve a huge list and do a count on it. Is there a way to easily do:

```
    mongoTemplate.countDistinct(query, "userId", OnboardingItineraryEntity.class, String.class);
```

Cause I've a huge number of criteria, so i find it sad to have to rebuild an Aggregate object from scratch ?

Bonus question, sometime userId will be null, Is there an easy way do count number of distinct (not null) + number of null in one query?
Or do I need to do a query, when i add an extra criteira on userId being null, do a count on that, and then do the count distinct on all and add them up manualy in my code (minus one).

Answer (score 0):

[MongoDB aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) solves this problem in several ways.

#### Aggregate with [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operator:

```
db.myEntity.aggregate([
  {$match:...}, //add here MatchOperation
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "$type": "$userId"
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nzUSbwlacsY)

---Ouput---

```
[
  {
    "_id": "null", //null values
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "missing", // if userId doesn't exists at all
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "string", //not null values
    "count": 4
  }
]
```

#### Single document with `null` and `NonNull` fields

```
db.myEntity.aggregate([
  {$match:...}, //add here MatchOperation
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "",
      "null": {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $ne: [{ "$type": "$userId"}, "string"]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      "nonNull": {
        "$sum": {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [{ "$type": "$userId" }, "string"]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9rpHxnLq58E)

---Output---

```
[
  {
    "_id": "",
    "nonNull": 4,
    "null": 3
  }
]
```

#### Performing `$facet` operator

```
db.myEntity.aggregate([
  {$match:...}, //add here MatchOperation
  {
    $facet: {
      "null": [
        {
          $match: {
            $or: [
              {
                userId: {
                  $exists: false
                }
              },
              {
                userId: null
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          $count: "count"
        }
      ],
      "nonNull": [
        {
          $match: {
            $and: [
              {
                userId: {
                  $exists: true
                }
              },
              {
                userId: {
                  $ne: null
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          $count: "count"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "null": {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$null.count",
              0
            ]
          },
          0
        ]
      },
      "nonNull": {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$nonNull.count",
              0
            ]
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZT5_3KYF9fy)

**Note:** Try any of these solutions and let me know if you have any problem creating the MongoDB aggregation.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed exemple with native mongo queries. However I was looking on how to do it, from my spring data api, ideally re-using the query already generated